# Using named_scope to get row count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails gurus: I've just discovered `named_scope` thanks to another SO user. :)

I'd like to get the count of a set of rows - i.e. a `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Additionally, I want to still be able to chain named scopes in the call.

Is this a legitimate (albeit weird) usage of named scope?

```
named_scope :count, :select => "COUNT(*) as count_all"
```

So then I can do (for example):

```
@foobar = Foobar.count.scope.scope.scope
```

The count is accessed via `@foobar.first.count_all`.

> **(Edited to address Allan's comments)**

You could do:

```
@foobar = Foobar.scope.scope.scope.size
```

But this would cause a result query and not the faster `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. I have a large amount of rows in the database I am querying.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is built in.

```
Foobar.count # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "foobars"
Foobar.named_scope.count # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "foobars" WHERE ....
```

If you run `script/server` in dev mode, you'll see the queries as they get executed.

Comment: Duh. Sometimes things are so easy in rails I miss the obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Please correct me if I'm worng but this doesn't seem to work if your named scope looks something like this:

def self.with_full_name
  select("users.*, CONCAT(first_name, last_name) AS full_name")
end

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is correct at all. Scopes are used to refine find statements and the count query won't play well with these.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do this, rails already gives you the means.

Using your example, you could just do this:

```
@foobar_size = Foobar.all.size #returns integer equal to total rows of Foobar
```

and even scope it like so:

```
@banned_foobars = Foobar.scope_to_find_banned.size #returns integer equal to total rows for "scope_to_find_banned"
```

Comment: This is what I originally had tried.

The problem with this is it doesn't take advantage of the fact that SELECT COUNT(*) is a relatively fast query. It would do a row query, and is much slower.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean.

Please forgive my misunderstanding.